# function top stack implementation in C

Tags: c, generics, data-structures, stack

I'm implementing a generic stack in C for learning purposes. This is the pop function of it:

```
void* StackPop(Stack *s) {
    assert(s != NULL);
    assert(s->logicalLen > 0); // there must be at least on element
    void *object = (char*) s->elems + (s->logicalLen--) * s->elemSize; // decrement logical length
                                                                       // on the fly
    return object;
}
```

In this case (StackPop) is clear to me that I must transfer ownership of the object at the top to the caller. So returning a generic pointer is fine because the caller is suppose to decide what to do with the object.
On the other hand I want to write a StackTop() function to return the top element. Here comes so uncertainty to me: I know that both functions should be very similar with the difference that I shouldn't decrement the size of the stack or return a pointer since I don't want the client to modify it. How do I pass a copy only of the top element then? Is accepting a generic pointer as an argument my only option and make a deep copy into that address?

```
void StackPop(void *target) {
    // make a deep copy into target address with memcopy or whatever?
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Unrelated, I'd start by writing `StackPop` to exhibit some semblance of sanity and check for an empty stack before all the other calisthenics. And pick a language: The fit and form suggests C; not C++.

Comment: @WhozCraig true, I just wrote it quickly. I'm actually not paying much attention to error checking at the moment. I'll correct it.

Comment: A "proper" way to settle your issue is to not have your pop function return *anything* (except maybe an error state). Only allow access to the "top" object (if there is one) via the top-function. If the caller wants a copy of the object, so be it; they can make one before popping. That is not coincidentally the way the C++ standard library container adapter `std::stack<T>` works. And btw, `assert` becomes a no-op in release-code, so you still need logical error checking, just in case you weren't aware.

Comment: Have you considered to return a const pointer like "const void*" or "const char*" ?

Comment: @juanchopanza c++ programmers are normally advanced c programmers. Besides, although not the best approach in C++ is still legal C++ code :)

Comment: Code written by "advanced C programmers" generally looks nothing like code written by "modern C++ programmers".

Comment: @blade Ehm, no. And it being legal C++ code doesn't mean you need to add a C++ tag. I will remove it, since there seems to be no good reason to have it.

Comment: First, as I would expect the first element of the stack to be at index 0, I would have written `void *object = (char*) s->elems + (--(s->logicalLen)) * s->elemSize;`. Next, in C I would not matter with copying an unknown structure. It can make or not sense depending whether the struct contains pointers in which case you get only a shallow copy. And here again it can be or not what caller could expect. I would simply state in documentation that `top` returns a pointer to a struct that should **not** be modified, and emphasize it by returning a `const void *`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta If implemented based on an array, to keep the top element at position 0, you'd have to move around a lot of data...

Comment: @Aconcagua: I wrote the **first** element not the **top** which in my understanding is the last inserted in stack

Comment: @SergeBallesta Ah, sorry, seems as if I had been inattendent... And then you are right, must be --l instead of l--...

Comment: The first StackPop function is logically returning a pointer to a nonexisting object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that both functions should be very similar ...

Who says that?

Your are designing the stack and therefore you are free to define all the rules for using the stack. For instance, your allowed to skip all checks for NULL pointers and just write in the documentation that calling function `xxx` with a NULL pointer results in undefined behavior. In the end it depends on what you want your stack to be - high performance, safe to use, easy to use, etc.

And the same applies to the `StackPop` and `StackTop` functions. You are free to set the rules.

To me your `StackPop`seems logically wrong. Returning a pointer to a memory area that has logically been freed by decrementing `logicalLen` is not what I would expect. But you can just write in the documentation that pointers returned by `StackPop` becomes invalid at the next `StackPush`. (In C++ some containers have such restrictions for iterators/pointers).

And the same goes for `StackTop` - you can just return a pointer to the top element and state that it is only valid until the next `StackPop`.

It's your design, your rules.

I would rather do like this:

```
int push(stack* s, void* o)
{
    // memcpy contents of o to next free location
    // increment number of elements held
}

int top(stack* s, void* o)
{
    // memcpy top element to o
}

int pop(stack* s)
{
    // decrement number of elements held
}
```

In all three cases the `int` is for returning error values.

For performance you could provide a function, e.g. `ptop` that returned a pointer to the top element (only valid til next pop).

Regarding `deep copy`:

There is no way you can do deep copy in a generic stack. If a user puts something in the stack that has pointers inside, the user must deal with it himself.

Comment: You could do the deep copy if the user supplied a function pointer specifying how it should be done.

Comment: @Hurkyl - yes, that would be possible. Personally I would still leave it to the user but it is a matter of design and - as already mentioned - as the designer, you set the rules. There is no right or wrong in this - just a question of what is the best fit for your current needs.